# jdbc select query not returning correct values

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, jdbc

Hello everyone I am running into an issue. Here is the code I am working with.

```
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue) {
                if (newPropertyValue) {
                }
                else {
                    sku=skuTF.getText();
                    try {
                        String result = "";
                        String query = "select * from NextDoor where sku=" + sku;
                        System.out.println(query);
                        Statement s1 = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery(query);
                        while(rs.next()) {
                            result = rs.getString("Quantity");
                        }
                        curQuantityLabel.setText(result);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem is occurring at the line

```
while(rs.next()) {
result = rs.getString("Quantity");}
```

I am getting error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '60-214' to data type int.
```

It is searching for the value 60-214 even though that is not the number I am entering in my GUI. I clearly specify in the query to select * for a specific sku which is  determined by a textfield. Any ideas why this is happening.

I am doing this in javafx and jre8

Comment: Looks like your sku column is defined int but you are concatenating "60-214" in the SQL?

Comment: But even in that case 60-214 would be evaluated to -154 at server side....

Comment: Stop concatenating user input into a SQL string and learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`. Your problem will then magically go away as a nice side effect well.

Comment: I'm new to this so I wasn't aware of PrepareStatement.

Comment: My sku field is not defined as an int. It is a string, I set sku = to the value of the text field then use that in the sql query. Is the sql query expecting an int??? I'm real sorry for not knowing how to do this properly. If it is expecting an int how do i select a sku like 60-204?

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
while(rs.next()) {
    result = rs.getString("Quantity");
}
```

cannot generate that exception, because you're putting a `String` (`rs.getString()`) into a `String` (`String result = "";`).

The problem is related to the `sku` variable instead, that from your code I suppose is a `String` as well; the exception you're getting is telling that SQL expects the value you filter the `sku` column on to be a number.

The solution is to check if `skuTF.getText()` returns a number, and only in that case pass it to the SQL query; something like this could work

```
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean oldPropertyValue,
                    Boolean newPropertyValue) {
    if (newPropertyValue) {
    }
    else {
        sku=skuTF.getText();
        try {
            int num_sku = Integer.parseInt(sku);
            String result = "";
            String query = "select * from NextDoor where sku=" + num_sku;
            System.out.println(query);
            Statement s1 = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()) {
                result = rs.getString("Quantity");
            }
            curQuantityLabel.setText(result);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e1){
            /* do something else here */
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

As correctly stated by others, `PreparedStatements` are the recommended way of generating queries and, if your `sku` column is not a number, using them will ensure your value is placed in the query with the right formatting:

```
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean oldPropertyValue,
                    Boolean newPropertyValue) {
    if (newPropertyValue) {
    }
    else {
        String sku = Integer.parseInt(skuTF.getText());
        String result = "";
        String query = "select * from NextDoor where sku = ?";
        try(PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(query)){
            stm.setString(1, sku);
            System.out.println(query);
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                result = rs.getString("Quantity");
            }
            curQuantityLabel.setText(result);
        }  catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In your first try you were probably just missing the quotes around the sku value

```
String query = "select * from NextDoor where sku = '" + sku + "'";
```

Comment: What do I do if its a sku like 60-204?

Comment: Good, but the suggestion of using PreparedStatements is still valid!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of error you have to use PreparedStatement instead, it is more helpfull and can protect you against SQL Injection, here is an example :

```
try (PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(
        "select * from NextDoor where sku = ?")) {

      stm.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(sku));//If your field of int type
    //stm.setString(1, sku);//if your field of type varchar

    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
       result = rs.getString("Quantity");
    }

}
```

Your error happen because you try to convert a String `'60-214'` to an int, so before you have to check your values, i assume that you your field `sku` is an int but `skuTF.getText()` return an invalid int.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing

```
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue) {
                if (newPropertyValue) {
                }
                else {
                    sku=skuTF.getText();
                    try {
                        String result = "";
                        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select Quantity from NextDoor where sku = " + "'" + sku + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                        while(rs.next()) {
                            result = rs.getString("Quantity");
                        }
                        curQuantityLabel.setText(result);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

This works, but is this practical? I'm still concatenating in the prepareStatement field. Can someone explain what is wrong with that?

Comment: This leaves you open to SQL Injection still. The purpose of prepared statements is to provide a template SQL query where the parameters are replaced by question marks (i.e. the literal symbol `?`) and provide the parameters in a safe way using the [`PreparedStatement.setXXX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) methods.